# I can only connect to local network computers through IP address, not network name

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, mac, wireless-networking

Randomly, my Windows PC (Windows 7, 32-bit) stopped talking to my Macbook Pro (Mac OSX, version 10.7.5, 64-bit). I can connect using the IP address from my Windows PC to my Mac by going to Start, Run, and typing in "//IPADDRESSOFMAC" and then typing in my credentials. 
However, if I go to Start -> Network and double-click on my Mac's name, it pops up with an error that says "Cannot Connect to NETWORKNAME, check the connection and try again" and gives the diagnose option, which never works.

I have never had any problems connecting to the Mac before. Even my mapped network folders don't seem to work. This problem persists whether it is a wired connection or a wireless connection and both machines can ping each other. I have tried rebooting both machines.

I have absolutely no problems connecting to my Windows machine from the Mac network screen.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just map a drive to it via IP; unless it doesn't have a static IP.  In that case, why not set a static IP and then map a drive to it by IP?

Comment: Are both machines on the same Ethernet LAN? Are both machines on the same IP subnet? Are both machines set to use the same Windows networking group or domain? You can check this last one on the Mac in System Preferences > Network > [whichever network interface you're using, such as "Ethernet"] > Advanced > WINS.

Comment: Spiff - Yes they are both in the same domain and group. It worked perfectly fine for 2 years, nothing changed. 

John - I can, but my question is why is this just now happening and how do I fix it? Not how can I work around it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Blairg.  I totally understand where you're coming from; if it was working fine for that long and suddenly stopped, I'd want to find out what caused it and how to restore the original access method.  I can't help but wonder if a recent Windows update is what started causing this...

Comment: It seems to be random. If I reboot both machines, it will fix the issue usually. Otherwise, I just deal with it and use the IP alone. I mapped the drives using the IP, so now it is just a random nuisance to find the IP of whatever machine I am trying to connect to.